# How to emulate Nexus 4?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, emulation

Is it possible to create an AVD to emulate the Nexus 4?

I am using Eclipse and I'm pretty sure I have updated all of the SDK tools etc, along with the 4.2 SDK/system Image etc.

However, when I open the AVD manager to add a new AVD, there no longer seems to be the ability to enter a custom resolution/density etc. There is a droplist containing several devices, but no Nexus 4, and no generic version with a resolution of 768x1200.

Am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need emulate resolution?

Comment: Yes, the resolution is important for me in this case as the app changes behaviour based (partly) on resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations as (if you want Nexus 4).**

In ADT21 version you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bhavesh! Can't believe I missed that 'device definitions' tab - I must just be stuck in my ways. Thanks also for the extra info on the layout editor - very handy!

Comment: Welcome :) you can also Upvote the Answer for make it more useful for other users.

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh - I have upvoted your answer now (I didn't have enough reputation to upvote previously).